# Passing a variable to a function in C

Tags: c

I understand that when a function is **called**, a frame for that function is pushed onto the stack, and when the function is done, we pop the stack frame and return to the caller.

But how about when **passing** a variable to a function in C? Does it work the same way as being called?

Comment: Are you following a tutorial or a book? What does it say?

Comment: depends on the compiler. it can pass the arg in a register, or on the stack.

Comment: Please post code that illustrates the difference between “a function is called” and “passing a variable to a function” are.

Comment: When a variable is passed to a function, a copy of that variable is made on the stack (or inside of a register).  If you pass a pointer to a function, it will copy the pointer but not the thing the pointer points to.

Comment: So that stack contains parameters of a function (its local variables), and we push the variable onto that stack.

Comment: But are we pushing the value stack(arguments) first or pushing the 'frame'(calling the function) first?

Comment: @user3692945 you shouldn't worry about where the variable are, because those are below the language... in the ABI layer, when you call a function the values could be in registers or the stack or on mars, the C lang doesn't specifically care.

Comment: actually you shouldn't worry about stack frames either until you get some more basic stuff down... like the function syntax apparently.

Comment: @user3692945: the space for the parameters (assuming they are passed on the stack as opposed to registers) is part of the stack frame (the frame contains space for parameters, local variables, the return address, and other items).  These are all implementation details and not specified by the language definition, so everybody does it a little differently.

Answer (score 1):

Techniques for argument passing depend on target architecture - CISC processors usually do not have many registers and thus use stack for that matter unlike RISC architecture. Statistics have shown, that more then 90% of functions do not have more then 6 arguments - meaning that compilers can optimize the code that all the arguments are passed in registers (which is faster than passing via stack).